# Read CSV line-by-line in Kotlin

Tags: android, csv, kotlin

I'm writing a simple import application and need to read a CSV file, show result in a grid and show corrupted lines of the CSV file in another grid.

Is there any built-in lib for it or any easy pythonic-like way?

I'm doing it on android.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/LiewJunTung/Kotlin-XML-CSV-Parser and also this https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/csvparser

Comment: I suggest marking one of the responses below as having answered your question so it's clear to the thousands of viewers. I think @KoyamaKenta who uses https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv is a great solution. Even PHPirate recommended that as a solution.

Answer (score 20):

**[Edit October 2019]** A couple of months after I wrote this answer, [Koyama Kenta wrote a Kotlin targeted library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57668121/4126843) which can be found at https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv and which looks much better to me than opencsv.

Example usage: (for more info see the github page mentioned)

```
import com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.dsl.csvReader

fun main() {
    csvReader().open("src/main/resources/test.csv") {
        readAllAsSequence().forEach { row ->
            //Do something
            println(row) //[a, b, c]
        }
    }
}
```

For a complete minimal project with this example, see https://github.com/PHPirates/kotlin-csv-reader-example

**Old answer using opencsv:**

As suggested, it is convenient to use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Here is a somewhat minimal example:

```
// You can of course remove the .withCSVParser part if you use the default separator instead of ;
val csvReader = CSVReaderBuilder(FileReader("filename.csv"))
        .withCSVParser(CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build())
        .build()

// Maybe do something with the header if there is one
val header = csvReader.readNext()

// Read the rest
var line: Array<String>? = csvReader.readNext()
while (line != null) {
    // Do something with the data
    println(line[0])

    line = csvReader.readNext()
}
```

As seen in the [docs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#even_quicker_start) when you do not need to process every line separately you can get the result in the form of a Map:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderHeaderAware
import java.io.FileReader

fun main() {
    val reader = CSVReaderHeaderAware(FileReader("test.csv"))
    val resultList = mutableListOf<Map<String, String>>()
    var line = reader.readMap()
    while (line != null) {
        resultList.add(line)
        line = reader.readMap()
    }
    println(resultList)
    // Line 2, by column name
    println(resultList[1]["my column name"])
}
```

Dependency for Gradle: `compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'` or for Gradle Kotlin DSL: `compile("com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6")` (as always, check for latest version in [docs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html)).

Comment: The last suggestion is not quite right - a call to`readMap()` reads only a single row from the file.

Comment: @DavidSoroko Thanks you are right, I have fixed the example.

Answer (score 9):

In terms of easiness, kotlin written csv library is better.

For example, you can write code in DSL like way with below library that I created:

https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv

```
csvReader().open("test.csv") {
    readAllAsSequence().forEach { row ->
        //Do something with the data
        println(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this `readAllAsSequence` read line by line? I am a bit confused here.

Answer (score 5):

Use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

This is gonna work like a charm for reading a CSV file.

As far as logging the corrupted lines is concerned you can do it using this logic.

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    try 
    {
         //execute commands by reading them using input.nextLine()
    }
    catch (ex: UserDefinedException)
    {
         //catch/log the exceptions you're throwing
         // log the corrupted line the continue to next iteration
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what class is input in your example?

Answer (score 4):

I used net.sourceforge.javacsv with my Kotlin code for parsing CSV files. It is a "java" library but within kotlin it is fairly straightforward to work with it like

```
val reader = CsvReader("/path/to/file.csv").apply {
  trimWhitespace = true
  skipEmptyRecords = true
  readHeaders()
}

while (reader.readRecord()) {
  // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Frankly speaking, it is quite easy to make a simple reader in Kotlin using modern Java features, check this (REMEMBER to handle [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) :-)):

```kotlin
fun processLineByLine(csv: File, processor: (Map<String, String>) -> Unit)  {
    val BOM = "\uFEFF"
    val header = csv.useLines { it.firstOrNull()?.replace(BOM, "")?.split(",") }
            ?: throw Exception("This file does not contain a valid header")

    csv.useLines { linesSequence ->
        linesSequence
                .drop(1)
                .map { it.split(",") }
                .map { header.zip(it).toMap() }
                .forEach(processor)
    }
}
```

Than you can use it as follows (depends on your file structure):

```kotlin
processLineByLine(File("./my-file.csv")) { row ->
    println("UserId: ${row["userId"]}")
    println("Email: ${row["email"]}")
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer that could be made more helpful with a simple example for new to kotlin dsl devs ie processLineByLine(file!!) { // do something with the map here }

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is BOM and why should we handle it?

Comment: [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is a Unicode character that can appear at the start of a file. It is magic, so it won't get displayed, but if it's there, you won't be able to match the first column header.

Comment: doesn't look rfc compliant, where new-lines are allowed within fields (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: Another non-rfc thing is that rfc allows double quotes to include commas in values, whereas this solution will ignore escaping and will split on `","`.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Csv files should be read with a real csv reader. A legal csv file can contain a record spanning multiple rows and commas within a single cell.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use your own data class for each row you should have a look at my solution https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/de/gmuth/csv/CSVTable.kt

```
data class User(
        val name: String,
        val phone: String,
        val email: String
) {
    constructor(columns: List<String>) : this(
            name = columns[0],
            phone = columns[1],
            email = columns[2]
    )
}

CSVTable.print(FileInputStream("users.csv")) 
val userList = CSVTable(FileInputStream("users.csv"), ::User).rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm a bit late, but I recently had problems with parsing CSV and there seemed to be no library good enough for what I was looking for, so I created my own called [Kotlin CSV stream](https://github.com/pelletier197/kotlin-stream-csv).

This library is special because it doesn't throw exceptions on an invalid input, but returns in the result instead, which might be useful in some cases.

Here is an example of how easy it is to use

```kotlin
val reader = CsvReader()
    .readerForType<CsvPerson>()
val people = reader.read(csv).map { it.getResultOrThrow() }.toList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it would be helpful if you copy a minimal example to here as well - I think it would more easily show the difference with the other approaches.

Comment: Good point. I edited the original comment to add that.

Answer (score 0):

For version of commons-csv version 1.9.0, have implemented below code to get results.
It uses CSVBuilder and CSVFormat to get records with skip headers and auto-identify headers on basis of first row.

```
fun csvReader(file: MultipartFile): ResultListObject? {
    var result = ResultListObject()
    var csvFormat=CSVFormat.Builder.create().setHeader().setSkipHeaderRecord(true).build()
    var csvRecords = CSVParser(file.inputStream.bufferedReader(), csvFormat)
    
    csvRecords.forEach{csvRecords->
        rowRecord.field1=records.get("field1")
        rowRecord.field2=records.get("field2")
        ...
        ...
        result.add(rowRecord)
    }
    return result
}
```